# I got a VBA" Run-time error 13 type mismatch" error even though I have given correct data type. What can be the possible error?

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

Here is my code. The error is in the highlighted part

Public last_row As Integer

Public corrected_mass_column As Integer

Public mass_column As Integer

Public quantity_column As Integer

Public stop_flag As Boolean

Public current_row As Integer

Public corrected_mass As Double

Public block_start_row As Integer

Public i As Integer

Public valid_man_count As Integer

Public sub_part_column As Integer

Public disclosure_column As Integer

sub code()

i = current_row

current_row = block_start_row

Do Until current_row = i

### corrected_mass = ((Cells(current_row, quantity_column) * Cells(current_row, mass_column)) / valid_man_count)

Cells(current_row, corrected_mass_column) = corrected_mass

current_row = current_row + 1
Loop

block_start_row = current_row

End Sub

Comment: You have defined quantity_column, mass_column and valid_man_count but i dont see initialization of those variables. Please check.

Comment: Did you check that the entry of the two affected cells is a number and not text or empty?

Comment: One of the entry was empty. I got it corrected! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign non-Zero values to current_row ,  quantity_column and mass_column after their definitions. ( cells (0,0) is not allowed!)

"Public block_start_row as integer" sets it's value to zero. So "current_row = block_start_row" sets current_row value to zero.

hope to helpful